# concatenate data.frame in a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have 100's of elements in a list. each element is a data.frame with same variable name. How would I collapse each element in the list and concatenate the data.frame

As an example, I have lista with elements k,l and m. How would I collapse each element k,l and m and create a new matrix with columns a and b with 15 rows ?

```
set.seed(1234)
k = data.frame(a=rnorm(5,10),b=rnorm(5,10))
l = data.frame(a=rnorm(5,3),b=rnorm(5,3))
m = data.frame(a=rnorm(5,15),b=rnorm(5,12))

lista <- list(k=k,l=l,m=m)
```

Comment: A very fast alternative is `data.table::rbindlist(lista)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to treat your list like a bunch of parameters to `rbind`.

```
do.call("rbind", lista)
```

Or you could use `Reduce` to bind them in one at a time

```
Reduce(rbind, lista)
```